# Is there a function for blockwise visual selection in Vimcript?

Tags: vim

I have two text files including shuffle steps, one is the main-file which has the entire steps and the other one is a sub-file has only part of steps of specific item. As follows.

[main-file]
SeqMain.txt

```
0001 K1G554   1  1 21-56 3  C- 2 1 0 0     0 D001
0002 K1H060   1  3 11-46 1 21-56 3 0 0 P   0
0003 K1G049   5  1 23-56 4  C- 4 1 0 0     0 D002
0004 K1H520   5  3 27-36 4 23-56 4 0 0 P   0
0005 K1G004  15  1 29-56 3  C- 6 1 0 0     0 D003
```

[sub-file]
SeqSub.txt

```
001 000x K1G554  C- 2 1 AY-29 1
002 000y K1G049  C- 4 1 AY-19 1
003 000z K1G004  C- 6 1 AY-09 1
```

And I always have to modify the main-file to change the sequence of steps many times. Every time the main file was changed, the step numbers in the  sub-file needs to be updated too.

Here is how I edit them by using VIM:

1.I sort the main-file by the column 46 `:sort/\%46`, put the cursor at row3-column1 and blockwisely visual select `ctrl-v` the row3-column1 to row6-column4 and yank `y`

```
0002 K1H060   1  3 11-46 1 21-56 3 0 0 P   0
0004 K1H520   5  3 27-36 4 23-56 4 0 0 P   0
0001 K1G554   1  1 21-56 3  C- 2 1 0 0     0 D001
0003 K1G049   5  1 23-56 4  C- 4 1 0 0     0 D002
0005 K1G004  15  1 29-56 3  C- 6 1 0 0     0 D003
```

```
0001
0003
0005
```

2.Then I open the sub-file `vsplit SeqSub.txt`, put the cursor at row1-column4, select and paste what I just yanked on it `1vp`.

```
001 0001 K1G554  C- 2 1 AY-29 1
002 0002 K1G049  C- 4 1 AY-19 1
003 0003 K1G004  C- 6 1 AY-09 1
```

3. Undo the main-file `u` and Write the sub-file and quit `:wq`.

I tried to write the steps above into a syntax file in vimscript or recording them `q` that I can source the script to complete the steps. The function `execute normal! ...` can do the same editing of normal mode. 
But in visual mode it did't work.

Does there any function for blockwise visual selection in vimscript? Or does anyone have a better solution to compare and update both files?

Answer (score -1):

You can work on blockwise selections with `:normal`, too. It's important to cover the *entire* command (i.e. selection and operating on it) there. To easily write the Ctrl-V that starts it, `:help key-notation` and `:execute` will help:

```
:execute "3normal! \<C-v>4E2jy"
```

Applied to your example text, this yields:

```
0001 K1G554   1  1
0003 K1G049   5  1
0005 K1G004  15  1
```